# Is there a way to automatically animate VectorDrawable by setting start and end vectors

Tags: android, android-studio, animation, vector, android-vectordrawable

## [AnimatedVectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.html)

I'm wondering if can create two **vector drawables** in **Android**, and animate it **automatically** from the first vector the second one.

Something like [**ViewTransiton**](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/index.html) and [**TransitionManager.go**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/TransitionManager.html#go(android.transition.Scene,%20android.transition.Transition))

Comment: The answer is largely no; you need to construct the specific animation yourself. I'm only aware of one tool that does some automation: VectAlign https://github.com/bonnyfone/vectalign but you will get mixed results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a drawable vector (**@drawable/vector.xml**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:viewportWidth="170"
    android:viewportHeight="170"
    android:width="500dp"
    android:height="500dp">
    <path
        android:name="my_vector_path"
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M85,40
                          c10,0 20,0 30,0
                          c0,-5 -10,-20 -30,-20
                          c-20,0 -30,15 -30,20
                          c10,0 20,0 30,0"
    />
</vector>
```

Create an animated vector (**@drawable/animated_vector.xml**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:drawable="@drawable/vector" >
    <target
        android:name="my_vector_path"
        android:animation="@anim/vector_animation"
    />
</animated-vector>
```

Create an animation (**@anim/vector_animation.xml**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="2000"
        android:propertyName="pathData"
        android:valueType="pathType"
        android:valueFrom="M85,40
                           c10,0 20,0 30,0
                           c0,-5 -10,-20 -30,-20
                           c-20,0 -30,15 -30,20
                           c10,0 20,0 30,0"
        android:valueTo="M108,35
                         c5.587379,-6.7633 9.348007,-16.178439 8.322067,-25.546439
                         c-8.053787,0.32369 -17.792625,5.36682 -23.569427,12.126399
                         c-5.177124,5.985922 -9.711121,15.566772 -8.48777,24.749359
                         c8.976891,0.69453 18.147476,-4.561718 23.73513,-11.329308"/>
</set>
```

The animation contains the `from` and `to` values of the vector path.

Finally, in code, start the animation:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
AnimatedVectorDrawable animatedVectorDrawable =
        (AnimatedVectorDrawable) getDrawable(R.drawable.animated_vector);
imageView.setImageDrawable(animatedVectorDrawable);
animatedVectorDrawable.start();
```

Comment: Good, but is there are any possibility to start animation without java\kotlin code? only in xml?